# laying out a jpanel with multiple custom components using swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to set up a JPanel using a BorderLayout in such a way to create a chart. For this, I have an axis component in the west & south regions and the chart itself in the center region. The problem is.. when I add my 'graph' component (basic class extending Component) and draw things onto it, this overlaps with the other axis areas.

I'm wondering how I can set things up in such a way that the reference for 0,0 from each component refers to it's particular starting point and not have all of them reference the same point (as is happening now).

Hope this explanation isn't too difficult to understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Swing components should never overlap when added to different areas of the BorderLayout. You must be doing something strange. Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem. Start with something simple first like adding a red panel to the west a green panel to the south and a blue panel to the center and you will see this is not a problem. Then try replacing the center panel with one that does some custom painting to see if you have a problem. In other words isolate which component is causing your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your graph really extends `Component`, note that you generally can't [mix AWT and Swing components](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/) that way. Try extending `JComponent` instead.

Alternatively, consider [`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)

Addendum: Even with a `JComponent` in the `CENTER` of a [`BorderLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html), `WEST` and `SOUTH` generally won't meet at a point, as seen in the API diagram.

Can you amplify on why [`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) isn't sufficient? It's never let me down, but you might also look at this [simulation's](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel) [`Histogram`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel/code#Histogram) class for another approach.

Comment: That didn't seem to make any difference. Unfortunately JFreeChart isn't close enough to what I want for it to be viable. Thanks for the help regardless.

Comment: @dylan: I've added more above.